# Why does my status bar color stop changing after I add a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a single activity with a BottomNavigation view which navigate to different fragments. I want to change the color of the status bar for each fragment. This works great apart from one fragment which contains a ViewPager. As soon as I remove this ViewPager, the status bar color changes as I expect it, however when I add the ViewPager, the status bar color does not change when the Fragment is inflated. What is the ViewPager doing thats preventing this color change to happen?

My Code for changing status bar color:

```
fun setStatusBarColor(@ColorRes colorRes: Int, isLight: Boolean) {
        window?.apply {
            statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this@BaseActivity, colorRes)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val lightFlag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR.with(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR)
                } else {
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
                }

                val darkFlag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
                } else {
                    View.VISIBLE
                }
                decorView.systemUiVisibility = if (isLight) lightFlag else darkFlag
            }
        }
    }
```

My Fragment which contains the ViewPager:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.x.x.android.ui.main.account.AccountFragment">

    <include layout="@layout/include_header_user_profile" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/account_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_layout_background"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_one_half"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_layout_selector"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="@dimen/padding_one_half"
        app:tabPaddingStart="@dimen/padding_one_half"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_primary"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/color_on_primary_unselected" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/account_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Main Activity which holds the NavigationController:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_background"
    tools:context="com.x.x.android.ui.main.HomeActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/home_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:elevation="@dimen/home_bottom_nav_elevation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
I can confirm that this only happens when the adapter is being set on my ViewPager. So if I comment out the code where I apply the adapter to the viewPager, the color change happens as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved this. In the fragments that I am inflating in my ViewPager, I was setting the status bar colour in the onViewCreated method of these, which was overriding the parent fragment, holding this view pager!